# I've implemented the same function with different approaches, can anybody tell me why my last function doesn't print false?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
public static void main(String[] args) {         
  System.out.println(hasPairWithSum(new int[] { 12, 4, 3, 4, 1, 7 }, 9));        
  System.out.println(hasPairWithSum2(new int[] { 12, 4, 3, 4, 1, 7 }, 9));       
  System.out.println(hasPairWithSum3(new int[] { 12, 4, 3, 4, 1, 7 }, 9));  
}

public static boolean hasPairWithSum(int[] intArray, int sum) {         
  int len = intArray.length;        
  for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (intArray[i] + intArray[j] == sum) {
                    return true;
                }
        }
  }         
  return false;
}

public static boolean hasPairWithSum2(int[] intArray, int sum) {         
    HashSet<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int len = intArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (mySet.contains(intArray[i])) {
                return true;
        }
        mySet.add(sum - intArray[i]);
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean hasPairWithSum3(int[] intArray, int sum) {         
    HashSet<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int len = intArray.length;
    return IntStream.range(0, len).mapToObj(i -> {
        if (mySet.contains(intArray[i])) {
                return true;
        }
        mySet.add(sum - intArray[i]);
        return false;
    }) != null;
}
```

Comment: maybe because (false != null) == true

Comment: Ok, any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: @CristianMateica we don't even know what your code is supposed to do. Your last method doesn't seem to follow the same logic as the first two, so why should it produce the same result?

Comment: drop the != null from your last line

Comment: Something to debate and wonder about `return IntStream.range(0, intArray.length)
                .filter(i -> mySet.add(intArray[i]))
                .anyMatch(i -> !mySet.addAll(
                        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(sum - intArray[i], intArray[i]))));`

Comment: @Niktar if I drop the  != null I will get an error

Comment: @Naman unfortunately is not returning true when expected

Comment: @Stultuske the methods must verify that there are pairs that sum the result of the sum passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams are lazy in Java. You need to call a terminal operation for starting evaluating the stream

"< U > Stream< U > mapToObj(IntFunction< ? extends U > mapper)" is not a terminal operation and it always returns Stream< Boolean > object, and it always not null.

You can modify your code like this, but I'm not sure that it's a good practice for using streams:

```
public static boolean hasPairWithSum3(int[] intArray, int sum) {         
    HashSet<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int len = intArray.length;
    return IntStream.range(0, len).anyMatch(i -> {
        if (mySet.contains(intArray[i])) {
                return true;
        }
        mySet.add(sum - intArray[i]);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should replace the `mapToObj` function with `forEach`. Then, I would just add the matching pairs to a List of array (the pairs) and finally, verify if that list is empty or not.

Here is a solution for your problem, inspired from https://www.baeldung.com/java-algorithm-number-pairs-sum:

```
public static boolean hasPairWithSum3(int[] intArray, int sum) {
    HashSet<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<>();
    int len = intArray.length;
    List<int[]> resultingPairs = new ArrayList<>();

    IntStream.range(0, len).forEach(i -> {
        if (mySet.contains(intArray[i])) {
            resultingPairs.add(new int[]{intArray[i], sum - intArray[i]});
        }

        mySet.add(sum - intArray[i]);
    });

    return !resultingPairs.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: thank you for all the explanations they are really helpful.